# Нахождение всех независимых путей в неориентированном графе

Tags: c, графы

Подскажите пожалуйста алгоритм поиска всех независимых путей в графе, если нетрудно пошагово объяснить! Хочу найти просто все возможные пути, чтобы не было общих вершин и ребер!

Comment: Вершинно независимых или реберно независимых?

Comment: вершинно, чтобы можно было потом пустить максимальный поток!

Comment: Так вам нужен алгоритм поиска паксимального потока? Поиск всех независимых путей может давать совсем разхные наборы этих путей, единственного решения вроде бы в общем случае нет.

Comment: Я сейчас задался вопросом как найти просто все независимые пути, хочу научиться их находить

Comment: Вообще-то максимальный поток в общем случае как раз даёт в качестве оптимума/максимума вершинно-рёберно-зависимое решение - особенно для максимального потока с мгновенной передачей. Т.е. непредставимое как совокупность независимых путей. Если у Вас иначе - имеются важные, но не озвученные, ограничения.

Comment: Задача в том что в опреденной вершине графа может находиться только один человек, из старта могут разойтись сразу по n доступным комнатам людей, и так же зайти в end, вот нужно оптимально быстро составить им маршрут

Comment: Максимальный поток я знаю как пустить, но вот сейчас хочу решить задачу о нахождении максимального числа непересекающихся путей в графе, чтобы не было общих вершин и ребер

Comment: *в опреденной вершине графа может находиться только один человек, из старта могут разойтись сразу по n доступным комнатам людей, и так же зайти в end, вот нужно оптимально быстро составить им маршрут* У Вас дискретная не-мгновенная задача? Или человеки, с их не-мгновенным перемещением - это неудачно подобранная аналогия? И - ставится ли задача, например, максимизации количества путей, минимизации количества непосещённых узлов и т.п. Ибо в текущей версии задача явно неоднозначна.

Comment: Вопрос состоит в нахождение путей чтобы они были независимы и максимальны для графа, я попросил подсказать кто знает как это сделать, для чего мне это я уже потом решу